# Complex integral of $\int_C (z-a)^n dz$, where $a$ is a given complex number, $n$ is any integer and $C$ is a circle of radios $R$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to compute the complex integral of $\int_C (z-a)^n dz$, where $a$ is a given complex number, $n$ is any integer and $C$ is a circle of radios $R$ and oriented anticlockwise direction.

My text book solution is given below.

[image]

**Doubt:** **$1$:** I am not sure why we are considering separate case for $n = -1$ to evaluate integral. While my thought was integral for $n = -1$ does not exist. As complex integral becomes infinity for $n = -1$.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why $n = -1$ is considered differently is that the integral of $e^{(n +1)i \theta}$ is equal to $\frac{1}{(n + 1)i} e^{(n +1)i \theta}$ only if $n \neq -1$. When $n = -1$, $e^{(n +1)i \theta} = e^0 = 1$, which integrates to $\theta$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.